# List of NuGet packages for a .NET SDK release

Tags: .net-6.0

Is there a list of NuGet packages that make up a .NET SDK release?

For example now that .NET 6.0.0 is released, I want to have a list of all NuGet packages that belong to this release.

- All runtime packages
- All ASP.NET Core packages
- All Desktop (WPF, WinForms) packages
- All EntityFrameworkCore packages (if possible)

Comment: Why? You have the assemblies that are part of the SDK, which do not require a Nuget, and you have the extension packages that come as Nuget. For the later, you don't need to have the latest version just because you use the latest SDK. So there's no nugets that "belong" to the SDK release.

Comment: Because we use to upload a copy of all NuGets that our application is using to a local package feed. This causes repetitive trouble/manual work whenever we want to update to a later (bugfix) version, e. g. from 5.0.10 to 5.0.12.

I expected to be a list or meta NuGet package somewhere that ties all the libraries/NuGets together. I mean they are shipped at the same time with the same version, most probably from the same build pipeline run.

Comment: So you are saying that if you use nugets that are older than the SDK release, you get trouble? Can you describe what problems? Normally, the SDK should stay backwards compatible to older packages, so I'm a bit surprised about the problem you describe here.

Comment: No, I'm not getting trouble with NuGets that are older than the SDK.

Comment: I'm just looking for a quick way to download all *.nupkgs that make a up a .NET release. E. g. download all packages that belong to version 5.0.12. We need this because we want to put them into a local NuGet feed for backup and offline purposes.